# uploading a DLL generated by a WBAPI requires the injection of interface services.？

Tags: c

In the netcore project, the project has started,

Uploaded a DLL file through the interface, which requires loading a DLL and implementing method interface injection

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1INjV.png)

Comment: The DLL has been loaded and injected, but the interface call prompts that the relevant service has not been injected

Comment: If you want to add information to the question, then it would be appropriate to [edit] the question. Comments should generally only be used for responding to other people's feedback.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.